# How to Print Star pyramid using for loops In this C language

Tags: c

Here is my code i am not able to print pyramid please help...

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i+=2){
   for(j=4;j>=i;j--)
       printf(" ");
   for(k=1;k<=i;k++)
       printf("*");
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Show the image of the pyramid you are going to print.:)

Comment: "Draw" a couple of pyramids on a squared paper, try to find the pattern for the leading spaces, try to find the pattern for the asterisks. Then convert those patterns to code.

Comment: Number of blank mistake. E.g `"__*__"` , front space is (5-number of *)/2

Comment: Well, you're close. I'm sure you can fix your code by working from the current result and adjusting the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter number of lines you want the pattern %d", n);
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < i + (i - 1); k++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code *does* print a pyramid, with one small mod commented.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i, j, k;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i+=2){
       for(j=4;j>=i;j-=2)   // loop by minus 2
           printf(" ");
       for(k=1;k<=i;k++)
           printf("*");
       printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my pyramids

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter the height of the pyramid (0-exit): " );

        size_t n = 0;
        scanf( "%zu", &n );

        if ( !n ) break;

        printf( "\n" );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%*c", n - i, '*' );
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ ) printf( " %c", '*' );
            printf( "\n" );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter sequentially 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 then the program output is

```
Enter the height of the pyramid (0-exit): 5

    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
Enter the height of the pyramid (0-exit): 4

   *
  * *
 * * *
* * * *
Enter the height of the pyramid (0-exit): 3

  *
 * *
* * *
Enter the height of the pyramid (0-exit): 2

 *
* *
Enter the height of the pyramid (0-exit): 1

*
Enter the height of the pyramid (0-exit): 0
```